# saving Spinner value to variable

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this bit.

I have 2 spinners in an activity, and I need to store the selected items/values as variables, which I can then send to a database.

my java looks like this, keep in mind that I am aware that my save() method doesn't make any sense. I just wanted to show you what I am trying to do.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_search);

    Spinner passengerSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ddlPassengers);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> passengerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.passengerArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    passengerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    passengerSpinner.setAdapter(passengerAdapter);

    Spinner directionSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ddlDirection);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> directionAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.directionArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    directionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    directionSpinner.setAdapter(directionAdapter);
    }
    public void save(View view){
    int passenger = passengerSpinner.getSelectedItem(); //Stored in a String array
    String direction = directionSpinner.getSelectedItem();
   }
```

I have no clue what to do to get those values stored as variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below,

```
String direction = directionSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```